# Xcode - how to change the name of the programmer into company?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I have app in iTune store but it shows my private name, app was made for a company, how can i show company instead of my name?

Like Google apps show Google inc but not programmers name.

Here Team: my name shows
Signing certificate: shows my name

[image]

Comment: I think it would be best, if they release it on their companys apple account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a developer account for your company. 
Say ABC Company

1. Setup abcdevelopment@abc.com apple developer account
2. Create certificates and profiles (Provisioning and Distribution) for the new account.
3. Then use this account in your Xcode, you will able to see company name in the Team option.

**Transfer app between accounts**

1. Go to your app in iTunes
2. Additional Information

[image]

See also in the official apple docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

**EDIT:** [LINK](https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit/?entityType=individual&requestType=migrateAccount)

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can move an app to another account. But using a company account would definitely be the cleanest solution.

Comment: You can transfer the app in iTunesConnect to your "company" developer membership

Comment: @YumYumYum There is an option to transfer the app from your personal to company account in itunes

Comment: You are genius. you have all the knowledge wow amazing..., i am just confused about the process now if i click that button, will my stable app which took 1 month to not get rejected, will be rejected or it will be just quickly transferred?

Comment: Ok awesome, didn't know that you can acutally transer apps.

Comment: We have to use transfer apps. Because i spend 1 month and not got paid for so much time from the company because Apple rejected my apps for 7 times and company was not paying me i lost a lot. Now company blaming me why app is showing my name, it has to there name. So to get out of this messed up issue, i just want quickly transfer everything to the company and make myself out from this mess. thanks a lot, hope it goes smooth this time.

Comment: @YumYumYum cool. haven't done that yet. So not sure how long it will take but apple are working faster now days. It will be quick. Fingers crossed.

Comment: https://appleid.apple.com/account?localang=en_US&appId=632&returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Fidmsa.apple.com%2FIDMSWebAuth%2Flogin.html%3FappIdKey%3D891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757%26path%3D%2Faccount%2F%26language%3DNL-NL%26rv%3D1#!&page=create - I am creating a new apple ID, but its asking my name, date of birth again? its for company, company does not have date of birth.

Comment: Can we again check to make it more clear. So create an account of Apple ID with which firstname, lastname and also of whos date of birth?